# Error heritage no access to a method C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

There is my code:

```
Fenetre *fen;
fen = new Fenetre(h, l);
tab_Ouverture[i]= *fen;


air_facade - tab_Ouverture[i].get_air();


Error:  error: ‘class Ouverture’ has no member named ‘get_air’
```

Thinks to know: 
Fenetre is child of class Rectangle. Rectangle got the method

```
get_air();
```

Fenetre is child of class Ouverture too.

There is my .h for class Rectangle, Ouverture and Fenetre:

```
#ifndef DEF_RECTANGLE
#define DEF_RECTANGLE

 class Rectangle {

 protected:
 float hauteur;
 float largeur;

 public:

 Rectangle();

 Rectangle(float h, float l);
 float get_air();

 };

 #endif

 #ifndef DEF_OUVERTURE
 #define DEF_OUVERTURE

  class Ouverture
  {

  };

  #endif




#include "rectangle.h"
#include "ouverture.h"
#ifndef DEF_FENETRE
#define DEF_FENETRE

 class Fenetre:public Rectangle, public Ouverture
 {
 public:

 Fenetre();

 Fenetre(float h, float l);

 };

 #endif
```

Definition of Ouverture and Fenetre:

```
   Ouverture *tab_Ouverture;
   tab_Ouverture = new Ouverture[5];


   Fenetre *fen;
   fen = new Fenetre(h, l);
```

If i i understand, Fenetre can't have access to get_air() method cause Fenetre is reconvert to a Ouverture Objet, and my Ouverture object aren't child of Rectangle?
How can i resolve this problem withtout do an heritance between Rectangle and Ouverture?

Thks!!!

Comment: Please edit your post with the declarations of `Rectangle, Fenetre` and `Ouverture`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you store these Fenetre objects as Ouverture objects?  If you are just going to use a Rectangle function then why aren't they stored as Rectangles?  But if you were going to use methods of both classes, then why aren't they still Fenetre objects?

Comment: Cause i have a similar class of Fenetre named Door (porte in french), just the name change.
So, that's why i want an array of Ouverture, which contain Fenetre and Porte objects.

Comment: Why we don't see Porte object in the code? Does Porte object have method get_air() ? If yes, than the method should me virtual and it should be in a Quverture class.

Comment: Even if i redefine get_air() in porte, i have the same error...

Comment: @Sandro: There's no need to show Porte because it is isn't (directly) relevant to the problem.

Comment: Nobody got an idea :( ?

Comment: The problem is that you have array of objects Ouverture , and if you want to call method get_air for Ouverture then this class has to have this method. Another solution (bad solution) is to use dynamic_cast to cast to real type of object during runtime.

Comment: But if i do an heritage between ouverture and rectangle to have this method, it's totaly absurd... No ? But i think i will do that. @Sandro

Comment: maybe it is better to inherit Porte and Fenetre from rectangle and have array of Rectangle class. because it is not clear why do you need Ouverture class without any methods?

Comment: Interfaces. A pure abstract class they both inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

Ouverture has no get_air() method.

get_air() is a accessible only for Rectangle and Fenetre classes (since Fenetre is also a rectangle)

Cast your pointer to Fenetre class, than it will work.

Comment: How can i do the cast please ?

Comment: You may cast like this:
((Fenetre*)&tab_Ouverture[i])->get_air();

but you need to think if wouldn't be better to change the type of your array...

Comment: I do like you say for the cast

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:  Firstly when you write

```
    tab_Ouverture[i]= *fen;
```

you *slice* your `Fenetre` object.  Only the `Ouverture` base object is assigned to `tab_Ouverture`, and the rest is thrown away.  If you want `tab_Ouverture` to hold different types of objects, it is going to have to contain (smart) pointers.

So your code needs to look something like:

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ourveture>> tab_Ouverture;  // Vector of pointers

    auto fen = std::make_unique<Fenetre>(h, l);  // Create a new Fenetre

    tab_Ouverture.push_back(std::move(fen));     // Move it into vector.  fen is now gone.

    ... 
    air_facade = tab_Ouverture[i]->get_air();
```

You will notice I have used a vector rather than a simple new'ed array, and std::unique_ptr.  The advantage of this is that it is *much* harder to leak memory, fail to call destructors.

The only issue is that this *still* won't work :-)  Your second problem is that `tab_Ouverture[i]` has static type of "(smart) pointer to Ouverture", and `Ouverture` has no `get_air` method.  There are two solutions to this:

1. Cast the pointer you get from `tab_Ouverture[i]` into a `Fenetre` pointer.
2. Give `Ouverture` a (pure) virtual `get_air` function.

The cast would look like:

```
    auto pFen = dynamic_cast<Fenetre*>(&*tab_Ouverture[i]);
    if (pFen)
    {
        air_facade = pFen->get_air();
    }
```

The rather strange `&*` is the simplest way to turn a smart-pointer into a real address.  `*` returns a reference to the object the smart pointer refers to; `&` obtains it's address.  (There are ways this can break, but you don't need to worry about them.)
I strongly recommend the virtual in `Ouverture`.

Comment: Oh my god, i havn't got the lvl to do this... =O
I will try.. Thks

Comment: Nah.  *Beginners* should use std::unique_ptr, make_unique, and vectors.  Raw new is only for experienced experts (who avoid it like the plague).